# CSS justified tabs with tricky active state

Tags: css, less

Here is the design for the tabs

[image: Here is the design for the tabs]

I need each tab to be the same width. The top green border on active tab should be over the left and right borders.

Here is the code I've written so far: http://jsbin.com/ricuzubo/1/edit

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is the issue you're having? It looks like it's working correctly in your example.

Comment: The green line doesn't go over the right border of the active tab.

Comment: If you click on the last tab you will see how all tabs should look when active.

Comment: @Andrew can you use CSS3- Box-shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying `border-right: none;` to your anchor tag, remove that style and add `margin-right: -10px` to it. This will do the trick.
[**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ricuzubo/7) and **[THE CODE](http://jsbin.com/ricuzubo/7/edit)** for reference.

```
li a {
    border: 10px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

li.active a {
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 0px green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS3 remove your border and add this effect using box-shadow.

Like This:

```
li.active a 
{
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 0px green;
}
```

Here is a FSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/BcA6K/

Comment: Could you update the jsbin example? I'm not sure if this is a good solution.

Comment: I updated my answer with a JSfiddle link. Could not figure out how to save on jsbin ;D

Comment: @NicoO If you notice, that box shadow you created doesn't cover the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your problem [here](http://jsbin.com/ricuzubo/13/edit?html,css,js,output) using some jQuery and CSS.

Good Luck!